# RecyclerView with NestedScrollView

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I am developing an android music player where I have album detail activity with collapsing toolbar and nested scroll view. Inside nested scrollview there are three textviews and a recyclerview see the code below,

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
       app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="@drawable/linear_detail_background"
       app:behavior_overlapTop="50dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/album_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="Album Name"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/album_artist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Album Name"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/song_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Songs"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:id="@+id/album_songs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

[The above code results in this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yaj0p.png)

The problem occurs when there are more songs, the image above shows the album name **This Party Gettin Hot** and the Artist name. But when there are more songs the **Album name and the artist name** is not showing.

[See this Image for Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gR9oF.png)

The Complete XML code is as Below

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_albums_songs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="@color/white"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/poster"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7"
            android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_album_detail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/linear_detail_background"
    app:behavior_overlapTop="50dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/album_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="Album Name"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/album_artist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Album Name"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/song_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Songs"
            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:id="@+id/album_songs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

how can I solve this issue? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I ended up adding a header to the recyclerView

Answer (score 0):

try change your nested scroll view layout_width to wrap content

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/linear_detail_background"
app:behavior_overlapTop="50dp"
>
```